# <a> over iFrame containing HTML5 expanding advert

Tags: javascript, css, html, iframe

I'm trying to implement an expanding banner ad on my site and I'm having trouble getting the clickthrough link to work.

I created an expanding ad in GWD and the only way I can serve it is by hosting it on my site and loading it in an iFrame.

I then need to wrap an  tag around that iFrame as I'm using DFP which requires me to put %%CLICK_URL_UNESC%%%%DEST_URL%% as the URL in order for it to track clicks.

I managed to get the iFrame to expand on hover using CSS but when I force the 
anchor to go over the top of the iFrame, the HTML5 banner inside the iframe no longer picks up the hover event.

[Here's a preview link to see it working](http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/preview_cookie?gct=wocj_91zKf8YvOHT1QUwvP2I3QWIAYCAgKCr2--xZQ&op=set&redirect=http://www.accessandmobilityprofessional.com&redirect_hash=AJlzBa2QytFct4LRif3y_C-P1msRV7v5dg&lineItemId=4616643051&creativeId=138228299907)

Here's the code I'm using the serve the ad:

```
<style>

.expandable {
height: 120px;
overflow: hidden;
transition:all .3s ease;
z-index: 5;
}

.expandable:hover {
height: 322px !important;
}

</style>

<iframe class="expandable" src="http://www.accessandmobilityprofessional.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/John%20Preston/index.html" height=322 width=1040 scrolling=no frameborder=0> 
<a class="expandable" href="%%CLICK_URL_UNESC%%%%DEST_URL%%" style="position:absolute; top:1; left:1; display:inline-block; width:1040px; height:120px; z-index:5;"> </a>
</iframe>
```

Edit:

I'm almost there now. I set the `<iframe>` and `<a>` to permanently have the expanded height, then I set the `<div>` to `overflow:hidden`.
By setting the `<a>` to `display:none` and then `display:block` on hover I almost have the effect I want. Since hovering over the ad activates the transition and the css on the div also expands the div and reveals the `<a>`

Now when I mouse over it expands the `<div>`, revealing the whole `<a>` and `<iframe>`. It also tells the HTML5 banner to reveal the second page. However, when I move the mouse off, it  shrinks the `<div>` and removes the `<a>` but the HTML5 banner doesn't detect the mouseout event since the `<a>` was in the way.

Here's the code now:

```
<style>

.expandable {
 position: relative;
 transition: height .3s;
}

.expandable:hover {
  height: 322px !important;
}

.expandable a {
 display:none !important;
}

.expandable:hover a {
 display:inline-block !important;
}

</style>

<div class="expandable" style="height:120px; display:inline-block; overflow: hidden;">
<a href="%%CLICK_URL_UNESC%%%%DEST_URL%%" style="position:absolute; top:1; left:1; display:none; width:1040px; height:322px; z-index:5;"> </a>
<iframe src="http://www.accessandmobilityprofessional.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/John%20Preston/index.html" height=322 width=1040 scrolling=no frameborder=0> 
</iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: `I created an expanding ad in GWD and the only way I can serve it is by hosting it on my site and loading it in an iFrame.` Why not serving it directly from DFP using DFP generated code?

Answer (score 0):

Putting the link tag inside the iframe as you're doing won't work -- that way the `<a>` would only be shown if the browser doesn't support frames (so, these days, basically never.)  Having the link contain the iframe also wouldn't work, as user clicks would never bubble up out of the iframe to your link href.

Assuming the contents of the iframe do *not* need to be clickable, and that user clicks should go to your `<a>`'s href:  you could treat the link as an overlay on top of the frame, and put the hover rule on a container:

```css
.container iframe,
.container a {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  transition: height .3s;
}

.container {
  position: relative
}

.container:hover a,
.container:hover iframe {
  height: 322px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <iframe src="https://example.com"></iframe>
  <a href="/"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: This is roughly how I managed to get the anchor to work before but while I don't need the content of the iFrame to be clickable, it does need to respond to a hover. So when the anchor or div is over the top of the iFrame the HTML5 banner inside it do anything when I hover over it.

Comment: See the snippet in my answer: the iframe does respond to hover (from the container element).

Comment: Wait, are you saying you want the frame to respond to hover on an element *inside the iframe*?  meaning the "HTML5 banner" is part of the framed page? If so, that's not possible (css rules can't cross frame boundaries, and javascript won't be allowed unless you have CORS access.)

Comment: Yes, that's right. The hover event is inside the iframe. I've tried another work-around but it's not ideal. See my edit. I'm now wondering if it would be possible for me to use PHP to swap out the URL inside the iframe after it's all loaded. That would mean I could ditch the `<a>` tag and just use the click event in the HTML5 ad.